# XAMPP alias or rewrite?

Tags: redirects, apache2, xampp

I have a site running on W2012 with XAMPP.  I have a live site that was in subfolder /foo.  It now needs to be changed to /home.

```
I set up an alias 

Alias /foo "C:/xampp/htdocs/home"
```

This takes users from foo-->home... however they lose the page that they were going to.  The problem is a lot of the pages on foo were privately given so we would be expecting users to understand that they need to copy their page to the new url.  I need a user going to foo/client-demo to go automatically to home/client-demo.

**Addition:**  Yesterday I set up a redirect.

```
Redirect foo/client-demo home/client-demo
```

This works.  Then I thought that the reason the Alias isn't working is my SSO.  I have an SSO SAML login script that redirects the user the their entry page.  So if the user starts at foo/xyz the alias kicks them to home/xyz (maybe on the xyz) and then they hit the login script and go back to their referral page.

Answer (score 1):

> ... however they lose the page that they were going to.

I'm not sure what you mean by this - they shouldn't "lose" anything? However, the URL in the address bar will not be updated - if that is what you are implying? An Apache `Alias` converts a URL to a server-side filesystem path (usually to allow access to files located outside of the document root) - it does not manipulate the URL.

It sounds like you want an external redirect (301 - permanent). For example, using mod_alias (prefix matching):

```
Redirect 301 /foo /home
```

This assumes that you are not already using mod_rewrite to process redirects/rewrites (such as with WordPress). If you are already using mod_rewrite for this purpose then you must also use mod_rewrite for this redirect, since the order of execution might not be as expected. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^/?foo(.*) /home$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried the redirect also and it does the same thing.  It does work if I set a redirect for a single page - see my update.

Comment: Not sure why it would work for a single URL and not as a general redirect. Just to clarify, an `Alias` and a "redirect" are two very different things, so ordinarily you should not get "the same thing" - unless there is _something else_ going on. I assume these directives are going in your Apache config? The "redirect" you have posted in your question is not correct (and would result in an _error_) - you are missing a slash prefix. (?) I'm not familiar with SSO SAML unfortunately, but you should be able to see what is going on by monitoring the network traffic in your browser.

Comment: Do you have any other directives on your virtual host? Any .htaccess files?

Comment: I just have the basic WP directory rewrite info in my htaccess files.  The redirect I have above works fine too - I know you are supposed to use windows path but it works...  The alias has me stumped.  I am mainly an IIS guy but have set up plenty of apache servers too - not sure if I had to do a wildcard redirect before (that's what we would call this in IIS).

Comment: The "WP directory rewrite" could be a problem (which is why I mentioned that the use of `Redirect` (mod_alias) is assuming you are not already using mod_rewrite). In this case you should redirect using `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) - I'll update my answer - since the order of execution might not be as expected. "you are supposed to use windows path but it works" - what do you mean by "windows path"?